# Passing vscode to external functions

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions

For my main entrypoint where my activate() function resides:

**extension.ts**

```
import * as vscode from "vscode";
import { subscribe } from "./eventListeners.ts";

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
  vscode.commands.registerCommand("mycommand.activate", () => {});

  subscribe(vscode);

  context.subscriptions.push(t);
}
```

I have split out event subscription into a separare file:

**eventListeners.ts**

```
import * as vscode from "vscode";

type VSCode = typeof vscode;

export function subscribe(vscode: VSCode) {
    ...
}
```

In the separate file I thought I would:

1. Pass in the vscode instance. There has to be some magic going on as vscode reads `vscode.commands.registerCommand` from activate() but does not run the other commands until the command is executed.
2. I want my code to be as typesafe as possible. That's why I have the awkward line `type VSCode = typeof vscode;` in there.

Questions:

1. Is there a better way to split event subscription out to a separate file than to pass in the vscode instance as I do?
2. Is there a better way to import the type in the separate file?

Comment: Why do you want to pass `vscode` to `subscribe` when you can just import it which you do anyways?

Comment: @md2perpe I'm confused at if that's how I should do it. Just import it. And if that is how I should do it always? There is something magical happening in activate() which is my concern. If I do certain things in it, like iterate over Object.entries(vscode.window) then the command cannot be found. It's not really documented how that magic works AFAIK.

Comment: How do you know that "vscode reads `vscode.commands.registerCommand` from activate()"? Is it because you find the command in the command menu?

Comment: @md2perpe I know it because if I write certain things (like iterating as I mentioned in my other comment to you) it can't find the command. So it does not only seem to be from the manifest. But maybe I am wrong, I would like to understand it perfectly.

Comment: By the way, I found out that we live only about 1 km away from each other, in different parts of Rissne, Sundbyberg, Sweden. It's a small world...

Comment: @md2perpe The reason I got a bit confused about this is that `Object.entries(vscode.window)` crashes silently if I put it in activate(). And then I get a weird error about using an API that I should not. Well, I guess it was the reading of some key done by entries().

Pretty cool! Yes that is close! In a world-wide forum. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already [adding a command as a contribution](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.commands) makes VSCode know about the command and display it in the command list.

But if your sole [activation event is when the command is run](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/activation-events#onCommand) then `activate()` isn't run until you try to use the command. So what the command actually does is not registered until the first run.

I think that the above is what confuses you. You see the command, so you think that `vscode.commands.registerCommand()` has been run, and therefore wonders why the other parts of `activate()` has not. But it hasn't actually been run yet.

You can try using [`onStartupFinished`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/activation-events#onStartupFinished) as activation event instead.

Regarding use of `vscode` in `eventListeners.ts`, just use `import * as vscode from 'vscode'`. There's no need to pass it around.